# Gradle: How do I copy servlet JARS to a folder in WAR file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, gradle, war

My build.gradle excludes jsp-api.jar, servlet-api.jar from WEB-INF/lib in WAR file:

```
ext{
    servlet = [
        'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.2',
        'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.3'
    ]
}

war {
    dependencies {
        providedCompile servlet
    }
}
```

I need those JARS in a separate 'libs' folder in the WAR file.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
war { from(configurations.providedCompile) { into 'libs' } }
```

should do.

Btw. the `dependencies` block inside the `war` block is misplaced.
It works as Gradle is very generous, but it should really be outside.